# Using a borrow as an associated trait type

Tags: rust

This code works:

```
struct Test {
    val: String,
}

impl Test {
    fn mut_out(&mut self) -> &String {
        self.val = String::from("something");
        &self.val
    }
}
```

However, a more generic implementation does not work:

```
struct Test {
    val: String,
}

trait MutateOut {
    type Out;
    fn mut_out(&mut self) -> Self::Out;
}

impl MutateOut for Test {
    type Out = &String;

    fn mut_out(&mut self) -> Self::Out {
        self.val = String::from("something");
        &self.val
    }
}
```

The compiler cannot infer a lifetime for the string borrow:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:13:16
   |
11 |     type Out = &String;
   |                ^ expected lifetime parameter
```

I cannot figure out a way to explicitly state the lifetime of the borrow, as it depends on the function itself.

Answer (score 6):

Taking inspiration from the [`Deref` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), you can remove the reference from the associated type and instead just note in the trait that you want to return a reference to the associated type:

```
trait MutateOut {
    type Out;
    fn mut_out(&mut self) -> &Self::Out;
}

impl MutateOut for Test {
    type Out = String;

    fn mut_out(&mut self) -> &Self::Out {
        self.val = String::from("something");
        &self.val
    }
}
```

Here [it is in the playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=5ed850c774c65ef45281e4fd74940b0e&version=stable). Given that your function name was `mut_out`, if a mutable reference is what you were after, [here is a playground example with that as well](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=57fe960bbb476bc6cf4af6a7c95a663c&version=stable).

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution will not work with my situation. I need to be able to return values that aren't borrows too. This is really just a stripped down form of the `Pipeline` trait of the project I am working [here](https://gitlab.com/rytone/resonant). (`Pipeline` is in src/pipeline/mod.rs) After looking a bit further, it looks like [ATC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265) will solve my problem, but there hasn't been any work done on implementing it yet.